# Jquery validation for a custom form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

In a webpage I am using a form which depending on current tab selection displays a upload file input or a text input.

Since am using the same form for both the tabs, jQuery validation is failing. I
am using both textinput and fileinput for validation, but if the form has textinput and no reportFile then its not submitted. I think its because when submitting, the validator is also looking for reportFile which doesn't exist.

I tried using depends but even that doesn't work.

Ex:

```
rules: {
    "textInput": "required",
    "reportFile": {
        required: "true",
        accept: "pdf"
    }
},
```

Comment: Is only one input visible at a time?  If so the hidden one should affect the validation result.

Comment: Yes, only one input is visible at a time.

Comment: what versions of jQuery validate are you using - later versions don't validate hidden fields by default (my earlier comment contains a typo - read ... shoudn't affect...)

Comment: If you want help with the jQuery Validation plugin, you should show the jQuery code for `.validate()` **along with** the HTML of the `form`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what you're talking about with, *"the same form for both the tabs"*, etc., because you have failed to show us any part of that code.  Where's the HTML for the form, at least?

However, [the rules on `reportFile` will fail because you placed quotation marks around a boolean `true`.](http://jsfiddle.net/J9dgD/2/)

This works perfectly fine on one form containing these two fields...

```
rules: {
    "textInput": "required",
    "reportFile": {
        required: true,  //<-- remove quotation marks from true
        accept: "pdf"
    }
},
```

**HTML**:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="textInput" />
    <input type="file" name="reportFile" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/J9dgD/3/**